# Android Studio change comments font

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

How do I change the comments font and style in Android Studio.

Currently the Code in general has the font Fira Code.

I want to make all comments have a different font with a different font style in my case italic.

I searched through the preference but I could only find these options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be pretty old, but I had the same problem and couldn't find any answer. I was not unhappy with Consolas as the Java code font, but the "l"s had a tail that made them hard to read in the comments.

If you go to File > Settings > Editor > Font (Android Studio 4.1.2) you can change the Font in the dropdown at the top.

This also changes the code font. I have not found a separate setting for comments font.

But I found changing to Lucida Console made the comments more readable and it was fine for the code.